# Does smartface support geolocation?

Tags: geolocation, smartface.io

I am just wondering if Smartface.io supports geolocation? I am looking to create an app that involves grabbing the coordinates of the user. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you take a look at the Smartface documentation?

Comment: This is not a good question for StackOverflow. It looks like smartyface.io points users to StackOverflow with the comment, "Ask Any Question!". However, StackOverflow is not a site to ask "any" question. This is a site for asking questions about programming. Good StackOverflow questions show research effort, are clear, and useful. Before asking questions here, you should do as @honk suggests and read some documentation. Please feel free to come back ask questions about programming. We love to answer programming questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

By using these keywords, e.lat and e.lng, you can get latitude and longitude values in onLocationChanged event of Global.

Take a look at this document, it will help you : 
http://docs.smartface.io/html/T_Documentation_LocationChangedHandler.htm